# Manhattan distance in 8 puzzle

Tags: math, prolog, sliding-tile-puzzle

Can anybody explain me how to calculate manhattan distance in 8 puzzle problem on this example [http://ai.ia.agh.edu.pl/wiki/pl:prolog:pllib:sliding_puzzle](http://ai.ia.agh.edu.pl/wiki/pl%3aprolog%3apllib%3asliding_puzzle) ?

How it's calculate this:

> a(0,0). a(1,0). a(2,1). a(3,2). a(4,3). a(5,4). a(6,3). a(7,2).
>   a(8,1).   b(0,0). b(1,1). b(2,0). b(3,1). b(4,2). b(5,3). b(6,2).
>   b(7,3). b(8,2).   c(0,0). c(1,2). c(2,1). c(3,0). c(4,1). c(5,2).
>   c(6,3). c(7,4). c(8,3).   d(0,0). d(1,1). d(2,2). d(3,3). d(4,2).
>   d(5,3). d(6,2). d(7,2). d(8,0).   e(0,0). e(1,2). e(2,1). e(3,2).
>   e(4,1). e(5,2). e(6,1). e(7,2). e(8,1).   f(0,0). f(1,3). f(2,2).
>   f(3,1). f(4,0). f(5,1). f(6,2). f(7,3). f(8,2).   g(0,0). g(1,2).
>   g(2,3). g(3,4). g(4,3). g(5,2). g(6,2). g(7,0). g(8,1).   h(0,0).
>   h(1,3). h(2,3). h(3,3). h(4,2). h(5,1). h(6,0). h(7,1). h(8,2).
>   i(0,0). i(1,4). i(2,3). i(3,2). i(4,1). i(5,0). i(6,1). i(7,2).
>   i(8,3).

in this code?

Comment: I can't understand, what's the meaning of these `a`-`z` predicates? All code on your link looks awful, with lots of asserts/retracts and tons of repetitive code (generated with some other language?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a,b,c,...,i` are the fixed cells names. The table is hand-coded to speedup the number of steps required to reach the *goal* - for instance, take `d(8,0).`, this only make sense because of `goal(1/2/3/8/0/4/7/6/5).`, that is, when cell `d` holds `8`, 0 steps are required...

Comment: I think it means 'unassigned' cell, will never 'fire' under normal execution, but could act as 'passport' to a general - but inefficient - solution schema, simply stating a general match condition for moving marker...

Comment: anyway, seems really a lot of (useless) code, the task can be solved easily as exposed, for instance, in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14769596/874024)